# Bubble Sort Parallel Arrays

Tags: java

I have run this program - the results are supposed to be

```
12,12.0
8,8.0
7,0.7
5,2.5
5,0.25
```

however when I run this program I am getting the results

```
8,8.0
7,0.7
5,0.25
12,12.0
5,2.5
```

I have tried my best to get the numbers in order as above first example
can anyone advise me of a solution

```
public class BubParArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int saleUnits[] = {5, 12, 5, 7, 8};
        double salePrices[] = {2.5, 12.0, 0.25, 0.7, 8.0};
        int pass, comparison, tempsaleunit;
        double tempsaleprice;
        String results = "";

        for (pass = 1; pass <= saleUnits.length - 1; pass++) {
            for (comparison = 1; comparison <= saleUnits.length - pass; comparison++) {
                if (saleUnits[comparison - 1] < saleUnits[comparison]) {
                    System.out.println("If saleUnits[ " + (comparison - 1) + " ]  <  salesUnits  [ " + comparison + "] \n ");
                }

                {
                    tempsaleunit = saleUnits[comparison - 1];
                    System.out.println("tempsaleunit \t" + tempsaleunit + " = saleUnits [ " + (comparison) + " ]");

                    saleUnits[comparison - 1] = saleUnits[comparison];
                    System.out.println(" saleUnits [ " + (comparison - 1) + " ]" + " = saleUnits [ " + (comparison) + " ]");

                    saleUnits[comparison] = tempsaleunit;
                    System.out.println(" saleUnits[ " + comparison + " ] " + " =  tempsaleunit " + tempsaleunit);

                    tempsaleprice = salePrices[comparison - 1];
                    System.out.println(" tempsaleprice \t" + tempsaleprice + " =  salePrices [ " + (comparison - 1) + "]");

                    salePrices[comparison - 1] = salePrices[comparison];
                    System.out.println(" salePrices[ " + (comparison - 1) + " ] = salePrices [ " + (comparison) + "]");

                    salePrices[comparison] = tempsaleprice;
                    System.out.println(" salePrices [ " + comparison + "] =  tempsaleprice  " + tempsaleprice + "\n");
                }
            }
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < (saleUnits.length); index++) {
            results = results + saleUnits[index] + "," + salePrices[index] + "\n";
        }
        System.out.print(" Sorted on units of sale \n" + results);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're having issues here because of how you structure your data to begin with. From the data, I infer that you have inventory on hand and the price you sell it for. So, are you really *sorting* the data or trying to establish which inventory goes with which sales item? Is there a reason the data needs to be structured like this? If so, why (that will help with the solution) and if not, restructure the data to start out in a more appropriate manor.

Comment: I apologise. All i am trying to do is sort two arrays in Decsending order that of salesUnits { 5,12,5,7,8} and salesPrices {2.5,12.0,0.25,0.7,8.0}   so the answer should be 12,8,7,5,5  and beside it the prices in descending order 12.0,8.0,0.7,2.5,0.25 It is an example excersise from the book which has the answer printed as I have outlined at the begining. and I am trying to find out why it is not sorting it like it should - thank you for your input - I know my code is all over the place but I am only learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI this is not bubble sort you are mixing selection sort and bubble sort ... 
Change these looping conditions

```
 for (pass = 1; pass <= saleUnits.length - 1; pass++) {
 for (comparison = 1; comparison <= saleUnits.length - pass; comparison++)
```

to

```
 for (pass = 0; pass < saleUnits.length; pass++) {
 for (comparison = 1; comparison <= saleUnits.length-1; comparison++)
```

also you need to change

```
if (saleUnits[comparison - 1] < saleUnits[comparison]) {
                    System.out.println("If saleUnits[ " + (comparison - 1) + " ]  <  salesUnits  [ " + comparison + "] \n ");
                }

                {
```

to

```
if (saleUnits[comparison - 1] < saleUnits[comparison]) {
                System.out.println("If saleUnits[ " + (comparison - 1) + " ]  <  salesUnits  [ " + comparison + "] \n ");
```

You need to remove this '}' and '{' 
You new code should look like :

```
public class BubParArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int saleUnits[] = {5, 12, 5, 7, 8};
        double salePrices[] = {2.5, 12.0, 0.25, 0.7, 8.0};
        int pass, comparison, tempsaleunit;
        double tempsaleprice;
        String results = "";

        for (pass = 0; pass < saleUnits.length; pass++) {
            for (comparison = 1; comparison <= saleUnits.length-1; comparison++) {
                if (saleUnits[comparison - 1] < saleUnits[comparison]) {
                    System.out.println("If saleUnits[ " + (comparison - 1) + " ]  <  salesUnits  [ " + comparison + "] \n ");

                    tempsaleunit = saleUnits[comparison - 1];
                    System.out.println("tempsaleunit \t" + tempsaleunit + " = saleUnits [ " + (comparison) + " ]");

                    saleUnits[comparison - 1] = saleUnits[comparison];
                    System.out.println(" saleUnits [ " + (comparison - 1) + " ]" + " = saleUnits [ " + (comparison) + " ]");

                    saleUnits[comparison] = tempsaleunit;
                    System.out.println(" saleUnits[ " + comparison + " ] " + " =  tempsaleunit " + tempsaleunit);

                    tempsaleprice = salePrices[comparison - 1];
                    System.out.println(" tempsaleprice \t" + tempsaleprice + " =  salePrices [ " + (comparison - 1) + "]");

                    salePrices[comparison - 1] = salePrices[comparison];
                    System.out.println(" salePrices[ " + (comparison - 1) + " ] = salePrices [ " + (comparison) + "]");

                    salePrices[comparison] = tempsaleprice;
                    System.out.println(" salePrices [ " + comparison + "] =  tempsaleprice  " + tempsaleprice + "\n");
                }
            }
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < (saleUnits.length); index++) {
            results = results + saleUnits[index] + "," + salePrices[index] + "\n";
        }
        System.out.print(" Sorted on units of sale \n" + results);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
If saleUnits[ 0 ]  <  salesUnits  [ 1] 

tempsaleunit    5 = saleUnits [ 1 ]
 saleUnits [ 0 ] = saleUnits [ 1 ]
 saleUnits[ 1 ]  =  tempsaleunit 5
 tempsaleprice  2.5 =  salePrices [ 0]
 salePrices[ 0 ] = salePrices [ 1]
 salePrices [ 1] =  tempsaleprice  2.5

If saleUnits[ 2 ]  <  salesUnits  [ 3] 

tempsaleunit    5 = saleUnits [ 3 ]
 saleUnits [ 2 ] = saleUnits [ 3 ]
 saleUnits[ 3 ]  =  tempsaleunit 5
 tempsaleprice  0.25 =  salePrices [ 2]
 salePrices[ 2 ] = salePrices [ 3]
 salePrices [ 3] =  tempsaleprice  0.25

If saleUnits[ 3 ]  <  salesUnits  [ 4] 

tempsaleunit    5 = saleUnits [ 4 ]
 saleUnits [ 3 ] = saleUnits [ 4 ]
 saleUnits[ 4 ]  =  tempsaleunit 5
 tempsaleprice  0.25 =  salePrices [ 3]
 salePrices[ 3 ] = salePrices [ 4]
 salePrices [ 4] =  tempsaleprice  0.25

If saleUnits[ 1 ]  <  salesUnits  [ 2] 

tempsaleunit    5 = saleUnits [ 2 ]
 saleUnits [ 1 ] = saleUnits [ 2 ]
 saleUnits[ 2 ]  =  tempsaleunit 5
 tempsaleprice  2.5 =  salePrices [ 1]
 salePrices[ 1 ] = salePrices [ 2]
 salePrices [ 2] =  tempsaleprice  2.5

If saleUnits[ 2 ]  <  salesUnits  [ 3] 

tempsaleunit    5 = saleUnits [ 3 ]
 saleUnits [ 2 ] = saleUnits [ 3 ]
 saleUnits[ 3 ]  =  tempsaleunit 5
 tempsaleprice  2.5 =  salePrices [ 2]
 salePrices[ 2 ] = salePrices [ 3]
 salePrices [ 3] =  tempsaleprice  2.5

If saleUnits[ 1 ]  <  salesUnits  [ 2] 

tempsaleunit    7 = saleUnits [ 2 ]
 saleUnits [ 1 ] = saleUnits [ 2 ]
 saleUnits[ 2 ]  =  tempsaleunit 7
 tempsaleprice  0.7 =  salePrices [ 1]
 salePrices[ 1 ] = salePrices [ 2]
 salePrices [ 2] =  tempsaleprice  0.7

 Sorted on units of sale 
12,12.0
8,8.0
7,0.7
5,2.5
5,0.25
```

Comment: Im really sorry the question was called bubble sort parrallel arrays you are right i am just trying to sort both arrays in decsending order side by side - i tried your solution it did not order the numbers for me

Comment: @rover2015 please check with the entire code cause it give me correct out put !

Comment: Ok it took me a while to see where I went wrong it is working now thank you very much i will study it now to see why it was wrong in the first place in the example we had the pass was set to          for (pass =1;pass<=salesUnits.length -1; pass++) I see now you must set that pass to ( pass = 0 ; pass <salesUnits.length; pass++) and the comparrison must be -1 and not - pass - I am very greatful for your help - I wish I could have figured it out myself - I did play around alot with the loops before I asked , Thank you so much

Comment: I printed out every line even to see where i was going wrong i couldnt figure out why it was not comparing I see now thanks :)

Comment: Done :) new to stack - I tried so very hard to stay away - I dont want anyone to do my homework for me !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Since i don't think i should be doing your homework, here's a pseudocode version of the algorithm for you to work from.

`procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
   n = length(A)
   repeat 
     swapped = false
     for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
       /* if this pair is out of order */
       if A[i-1] > A[i] then
         /* swap them and remember something changed */
         swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
         swapped = true
       end if
     end for
   until not swapped
end procedure`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incredibly difficult to follow. I would start by implementing methods to swap elements in my two types of arrays,

```
private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) {
        return;
    }
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

private static void swap(double[] arr, int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) {
        return;
    }
    double temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

Then synchronize the `swap`(s) like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int saleUnits[] = { 5, 12, 5, 7, 8 };
    double salePrices[] = { 2.5, 12.0, 0.25, 0.7, 8.0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < saleUnits.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < saleUnits.length; j++) {
            if (saleUnits[i] < saleUnits[j]) {
                swap(saleUnits, i, j);
                swap(salePrices, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < saleUnits.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%2d %.2f%n", saleUnits[i], salePrices[i]);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
12 12.00
 8 8.00
 7 0.70
 5 2.50
 5 0.25
```

**Edit**

Of course, it's more efficient to create a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) and use the built in sort like

```
static class SalesData implements Comparable<SalesData> {
    final int units;
    final double price;

    public SalesData(int units, double price) {
        this.units = units;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s", units, price);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SalesData o) {
        if (this.units != o.units) {
            return -Integer.valueOf(this.units).compareTo(o.units);
        }
        return -Double.valueOf(this.price).compareTo(o.price);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int saleUnits[] = { 5, 12, 5, 7, 8 };
    double salePrices[] = { 2.5, 12.0, 0.25, 0.7, 8.0 };
    SalesData[] data = new SalesData[saleUnits.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < saleUnits.length; i++) {
        data[i] = new SalesData(saleUnits[i], salePrices[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(data);
    for (SalesData sdt : data) {
        System.out.println(sdt);
    }
}
```